# how to populate attribute via managed bean?

Tags: oracle-adf

i have a jsf page with a form, i need to update an attribute of the form (current obviously) via a managed bean (via a button).
The managed bean in question already exists and do other code , which is uploading a file to the server and getting the full file path (it returns a string lets say file_name).
I want the attribute of the form (an input text named path) to get the file_name value each time a file is uploaded

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way to programmatically set a value of a view attribute in Oracle ADF, Here is two of them :

1. The JSF way using the highly recommended JSFUtils.java library function :

```java
/**
 * Method for setting a new object into a JSF managed bean
 * Note: will fail silently if the supplied object does
 * not match the type of the managed bean.
 * @param expression EL expression
 * @param newValue new value to set
 */
public static void setExpressionValue(String expression, Object newValue) {
    FacesContext facesContext = getFacesContext();
    Application app = facesContext.getApplication();
    ExpressionFactory elFactory = app.getExpressionFactory();
    ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
    ValueExpression valueExp = elFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, expression, Object.class);

    //Check that the input newValue can be cast to the property type
    //expected by the managed bean.
    //If the managed Bean expects a primitive we rely on Auto-Unboxing
    Class bindClass = valueExp.getType(elContext);
    if (bindClass.isPrimitive() || bindClass.isInstance(newValue)) {
        valueExp.setValue(elContext, newValue);
    }
}

JSFUtils.setExpressionValue("#{bindings.YOUR_VO_ATTRIBUTE.inputValue}","YOUR VALUE");
```

2. By binding the jsf component to your ADF Bean

Go To your component > Open property inspector > Set Binding Attribute to your Bean (will create the following getter and setter)

```java
public void setMyInputText(RichInputText myInputText) {
    this.myInputText = myInputText;
}

public RichInputText getMyInputText() {
    return myInputText;
}

//then in your action you can just set and refresh component 
this.setMyInputText(YourValue);
AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(this.getMyInputText);
```

https://gist.github.com/CedricL46/6cc291ce80601f50b66973e1000690a9